# Meaning of these verses from Nyaya Sutras?

Tags: nyaya, interpretation, nyaya-sutra, exegesis, hermeneutics

(4.1.19)

> Ishvara is the cause, since we see sometimes human action lacks fruits (results).

(4.1.20)

> This is not so since, as a matter of fact, no fruit is accomplished without human action.

(4.1.21)

> Not so, since it (human action?) is influenced by him (God?)

What does this mean? Is it saying God exists or that he doesn't exist?

Comment: it says everyaction is done by god

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Is it saying that every action is done by God or influenced by God?

Comment: Whatever you take both are true in some sense

Comment: What is that you don't understand? It is trying to prove the existence God.

Comment: The earlier comments have already answered basically what 4.1.19-21 are attempting, I would further recommend you to check the commentaries of Vātsyāyana, Uddyotakara and Vācaspati Miśra. Sūtra texts should always be read along with commentaries to understand them well. 
Other than that, I would recommend the Chapter 6 (pp. 116-136) of this book 
https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/12144133
It explains 4.1.19-21 in more detail with commentaries and explanations, focusing on Nyāya theism specifically.